# How to center ndv3 lineChart

Tags: html, nvd3.js

I'm a total noob to html and javascript so please pardon my ignorance. I want to create a `nvd3` chart. I'm passing data to `ndv3` and generating a chart html file. How to center the chart such that it aligns to the center rather than to the left, and also how to align the legend to the right side. Here's the file content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="linechart_with_interactive_guideline">
        <svg style="width:600px;height:400px;"></svg>
    </div>

    <script>
        data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline = [{
            "values": [{
                "y": 2688202.88,
                "x": 1492297200000.0
            }, {
                "y": 7597414.21,
                "x": 1492383600000.0
            }, {
                "y": 2881684.29,
                "x": 1492470000000.0
            }, {
                "y": 5068672.55,
                "x": 1492556400000.0
            }, {
                "y": 3707031.11,
                "x": 1492642800000.0
            }, {
                "y": 4088938.01,
                "x": 1492729200000.0
            }],
            "key": "traffic",
            "yAxis": "1"
        }];

        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart().useInteractiveGuideline(true);

            chart.margin({
                top: 60,
                right: 60,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 80
            });

            var datum = data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline;

            chart.xAxis
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format.utc('%d %b %Y')(new Date(parseInt(d)))
                });
            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

            chart.showLegend(true);

            d3.select('#linechart_with_interactive_guideline svg')
                .datum(datum)
                .transition().duration(500)
                .attr('width', 600)
                .attr('height', 400)
                .call(chart);

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. I believe you want your chart to be display center of browser? If that's what you're looking for. Edit your code like this

```
        <center>
        <svg style="width:600px;height:400px;"></svg>
        </center>
```

This is the simplest way you can do with html.